# Performance differences in array handling

Tags: c, memory, struct, runtime

I have this code:

```
typedef struct
{
int a[4];
} ArrStruct;

void printSizeOfArray(ArrStruct arrStruct)
{
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(arrStruct.a));
++(arrStruct.a[2]);
}

int main()
{

int it;
ArrStruct arrStruct;
printSizeOfArray(arrStruct);

for (it = 0 ; it < sizeof(arrStruct.a)/sizeof(int); ++it)
{
printf("%d, ", arrStruct .a[it]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Someone told that it does not have a good runtime/memory performance compared to this next code. What is the difference?

```
void printSizeOfArray(int a[])

{
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(a));
++(a[2]);
}

int main()
{

int it;
int a[4] = {0};
printSizeOfArray(a);
for (it = 0 ; it < sizeof(a)/sizeof(int) ; ++it)
{
printf("%d, ", a[it]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Why would the second code have better performance?

Comment: You array uses 16 bytes. The time for handling that will be in the order of nanoseconds. Nobody will notice if it is half a ns faster or slower.

Answer (score 1):

In the first code, the structure `ArrStruct` is used by value, so, in the function `printSizeOfArray`, the member `a` of the structure won't be converted to a pointer. So there will be `4 * sizeof(int) - sizeof(int *)` (plus potential padding bytes) more on the stack. Check the produced assembly, to know whether the first or the second code is more efficient.

In theory, the second code would run faster, because there is less derefences. However, with optimizations turned on, there is no significiant differences.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there would be much difference between the two with optimisation turned on.  But why would you want to code it like that. What advantage do you think the struct containing an array has over the array?  Unless you want to add more things to the struct, just use an array.

Edit:

... on second thought, your code is to 'print the size of the array'?  Your second code is not complete (paste error?) but the size of an array will not be apparent inside the function whereas the size of the struct and hence its array will.

Answer (score 1):

The only reasonable performance concern is probably that in `printSizeOfArray` the `ArrStruct` is passed by value. That means it will be copied when the function is called, and this is unnecessary. If you pass the parameter by pointer this issue goes away:

```
vaid printSizeOfArray(ArrStruct *arrStruct)
{
   printf("%lu\n", sizeof(arrStruct->a));
   ++(arrStruct->a[2]);
}
```

Additionally, the alternative `printSizeOfArray` function that takes an array won't work correctly. The parameter ends up being interpreted as a `int*`, and then the `sizeof` calculations in the functions don't do the intended thing.